# What is exactly GPU dimension

Tags: graphics-cards, pcie

[image]

I wonder that what is the distance between top of PCIe x 16 connector and top of GPU card? I think it has a constant value, so if constant value, it will be recommended in any document, but I can't find anything related to it.
Anyone can help me?

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reference document for this is [PCI-E Card electromechanical specification](http://read.pudn.com/downloads166/ebook/758109/PCI_Express_CEM_1.1.pdf). I believe the relevant figure is 6.2:

[image]

As you can see, the distance you're asking about is not specified at all, because the lug (referred to as "detail F" in the figure) has no connectivity and is present to prevent insertion of PCI-E cards into PCI slots. It doesn't have to be positioned at a precise distance from the bracket for the card to work.

What is specified is the distance between the card bracket and the notch inside the connector, which is 59,05mm.